# Merge 2 data responses from json

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

If i do this for argument sake :

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlOne/?format=json'),
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlTwo/?format=json')
).then(function () {
    // how can i merge the response from both json requests before processing them
});
```

Both url's are on the twitter api but one is a keyword search and one is just a regular user timeline call.

I am trying to amend a twitter plugin, to show both the username timeline (in the fist json request) and @username mentions by searching for @username (in the second json request)

See current function i want to amend to call 2 urls and merge the data before processing it :

```
  $.getJSON(build_api_url(), function(data){
    var tweets = $.map(data.results || data, extract_template_data);
    tweets = $.grep(tweets, s.filter).sort(s.comparator).slice(0, s.count);
    $(widget).trigger("tweet:retrieved", [tweets]);
  });
```

This does not work :

```
 $.when(
  $.getJSON(build_api_url(),
  $.getJSON(build_user_url()
  ).done( function(json1, json2) {
 var data = $.extend(json1, json2)
      // json1 and json2 represent the returned json, so just combine them as needed here
      var tweets = $.map(data.results || data, extract_template_data);
      tweets = $.grep(tweets, s.filter).sort(s.comparator).slice(0, s.count);
      $(widget).trigger("tweet:retrieved", [tweets]);
  });
```

Comment: how exactly do you want to merge the objects? How should duplicate keys be resolved? More importantly, what benefit would you expect to get out of merging the two objects into one over just iterating over each object independently?

Comment: Currently the plugin is calling one url in the get data function, and handling the response data and passing it on. So i had hoped that calling 2 urls at this point and merging the data here, would suffice, before passing that data on to the remaining functions that format the data.

Comment: Added example to original question

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlOne/?format=json'),
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlTwo/?format=json')
).then(function (a1, a2) {
    // First get the two objects from json
    // (you could check statusText in a1[1] if desired) :
    var obj1 = JSON.parse(a1[2].responseText);
    var obj2 = JSON.parse(a2[2].responseText);
    // Then, if you want to "merge" them you can do this :
    var obj = obj1;
    for (var key in obj2) {
        obj[key] = obj2[key]; // this will replace obj1[key] you have to know how you want to merge
    }
    // use obj
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by exploring [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). Something like `$.extend(json1, json2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to use `$.when().done()` approach like this:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlOne/?format=json'),
    $.getJSON('http://myUrlTwo/?format=json')
).done( function(json1, json2) {
    // json1 and json2 represent the returned json, so just combine them as needed here
});
```

Of course if you need to handle failures on the request, then you would need to use `$.when().then()` . You didn;t show use of a failure callback in your example, taht is why I suggested `done()` instead of `then()`.